# $a_{-1}$ in the Laurent series of $\frac{1} {\sin (z)}$ at $0$.

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series, singularity

So I am having issues with the following function:

$f(z)=\frac{1}{\sin(z)}-\frac{1}{z}$

I need to find that $a_{-1}$ in the Laurent series of $\frac{1} {\sin (z)}$ at $0$.

So firstly I went and proved that $f(z)=\frac{1}{\sin(z)}-\frac{1}{z}$ has a removable singularity at $0$.

It should be clear that $\frac{1}{z}$ has a simple pole at $z = 0$.

We also know the Taylor series of $\sin(z)$ and indeed the roots of $\sin(z)$; namely $n\pi,n \in \mathbb Z$.

Thus ord$(\sin(z),n\pi) = 1$ so that ord${(\frac{1}{\sin(z)} ,n\pi)}= −1$;

i.e. $\frac{1}{\sin(z)}$ has simple poles at $n\pi$. Thus $f$ has simple poles at $n\pi$ for $n \in \mathbb Z/(0)$.

What happens at $z = 0$? Rewriting gives

$f(z) = \frac{z−\sin(z)}{ z \sin(z)}$

where

$z−\sin(z) =\frac{z^3}{ 3!}- \frac{z^5}{ 5!}+ …$

and

$z \sin(z) = z^2−\frac{z^4}{4!}…$

so that

ord$(z−\sin(z),0) = 3$, and ord$(z\sin(z),0) = 2$

ord$(f,0) = 1$.

Thus $f$ has a removable singularity at $z = 0$. Deﬁning $f(0) = a_0 = 0$ makes $f$ diﬀerentiable at $z = 0.$

How do I use what I have shown to find $a_{-1}$ in the Laurent Series of $\frac{1}{\sin(z)}$

Comment: $\dfrac z{\sin z}=\dfrac z{z-\frac{z^3}{3!}+\cdots}=\dfrac1{1-\frac{z^3}{3!}+\cdots}=1+\dfrac{z^2}{3!}\cdots$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I'm sorry but could you explain what that means.. I'm not sure what you are trying to show me here. Thanks

Comment: @gavin it is common to use polynomial long division or undetermined coefficients on a truncated Taylor's series to find the $a_{-1}$ coefficient.

Comment: @Argon thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $f$ has a removable singularity at $0$ and since $f(0)=0$ we can write

$$f(z)=a_1z+a_2z^2+a_3z^3+....$$

in a neighborhood of $0$.

Since $\frac{1}{ \sin z}=f(z)+\frac{1}{z}$ we have

$$\frac{1}{ \sin z}=\frac{1}{z}+a_1z+a_2z^2+a_3z^3+....$$

in a deleted neighborhood of $0$.

Thus $a_{-1}=1.$

A furthr possibility:$g(z):=\frac{1}{ \sin z}$ has a simple pole at $0$. Thus

$$a_{-1}=Res(g;0)= \lim_{z \to 0}zg(z)=1.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\gamma$ be a little contour oriented counterclockwise around the origin. Then
$$
\int_\gamma f = 2\pi i\cdot  a_{-1}.
$$
On the other hand, the left hand side is zero since the singularity at the origin is removable.